# Jasmine Testing: Expected undefined to equal Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am new to AngularJS. I have created the following component that contains a template and an associated controller.

```
angular.
module('beerDetail').
controller('BeerDetailController',  ['BeerSelection', '$scope', '$rootScope',
  function BeerDetailController(BeerSelection, $scope, $rootScope) {

    let beerSelected = BeerSelection.getBeerSelected();

    $scope.ok = () => { $rootScope.modalInstance.close() };
    $scope.beer = beerSelected;
    $scope.foodPairings = beerSelected.food_pairing.join(", ");

    this.getFormattedIngredients = (ingredients) => {...};

    this.getFormattedMethod = (method) => {...};

    $scope.allIngredients = this.getFormattedIngredients(beerSelected.ingredients);
    $scope.method = this.getFormattedMethod(beerSelected.method);
  }
]).
component('beerDetail', {
  templateUrl: '/components/beer-detail/beer-detail.template.html',
  controller: 'BeerDetailController',
});
```

I would like to test the controller, I have created the following test that check whether the beer passed into the scope is the one provided by calling: `BeerSelection.getBeerSelected()` :

```
describe('BeerDetailController', function() {

  it('returns the selected beer', function() {

      beforeEach(module('beerDetail'));

      let $controller;
      let scope;
      let rootScope;
      let createController;
      let beerSelection;
      let beerSelected = {
        "id": 192,
        "name": "Punk IPA 2007 - 2010",
      };

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function () {
          return $controller('BeerDetailController',
            {'BeerSelection': beerSelection},
            {'$scope': scope},
            {'$rootScope': rootScope}
            );
          spyOn(beerSelection, 'getBeerSelected').and.returnValues(beerSelected);
        };
    }));

    expect(scope.beer).toEqual(beerSelected);
    });
  });
```

I do get the following error however:

> Expected undefined to equal Object({ id: 192, name: 'Punk IPA 2007 -
>   2010' })

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the `createController` method to actually create it. Is just made an assignment youy did in your beforeEach.

```
createController();     
expect(scope.beer).toEqual(beerSelected);
```

should be working

To register (edit from comment) :

```
angular.
module('beerDetail').
controller('BeerDetailController',  {your controller function}).
component('beerDetail', {
  templateUrl: '/components/beer-detail/beer-detail.template.html',
  controller: 'BeerDetailController'
....
```

I think this sould work

Comment: Thanks! I do get now: The controller with the name 'BeerDetailController' is not registered.. Why is that?

Comment: Everything custom (not apply to angular service like $scope, ...) passing by to the controller with simple quote  must be register to the module. I lgive the angular doc to help you : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. It's works the same way as Spring CDI.

Comment: mmm I am bit confused now. Where should I register BeerDetailController?

Comment: This is what I have in the beerDetail module:
angular.module('beerDetail', ['core.beer-selection']);

Comment: I'm not used with angular v2 syntax... But I think you have to extract the controller. I'll modify my answer...

Comment: Eric many thanks for your help. I have made the changes, but I got now: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- BeerDetailController